# Connecting two clients openvpn

Tags: vpn, routing, ip, openvpn

I have two clients one connected to vpn server through vpn and another without vpn. I can ping both the clients from my server but I can't do directly using one client to another.

I am adding route tables for all these clients and server. Please note 10.10.0.2 and 10.10.0.1 are vpn private ip.

Route table for all the three are:

```
Kernel IP routing table for 10.30.0.190 vpn client
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.30.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.20.0.0       10.10.0.1       255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.30.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0


route table for 10.20.0.180 private subnet connected to vpn
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.20.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.20.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

route table for 10.20.0.99 - vpn server
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.20.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.20.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.30.0.0       10.10.0.2       255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely missing routes.

On your VPN server, add this directive to add routes to your local subnet: `push 
"route 10.20.0.0 255.255.255.0"`.  That will tell VPN clients to route traffic through the VPN for that subnet.  It looks like you might have done this, but be aware that yours has a subnet mask of /16 while the routing table on the LAN client has /24.

On your gateway router 10.20.0.1, be sure to add a route for 10.10.0.0/24 through the VPN server (i.e. `ip route add 10.10.0.0/24 via 10.20.0.99`) so that the return path is also routeable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have already enabled client to client. But one client is not on vpn.

Comment: Oops, missed that.  Corrected.

Comment: I did, i am using aws so added routes there. sadly didn't fixed problem.

Comment: If you are using AWS, you might have to add the routes to the routing table for the subnet, depending on what you are using AWS for.